# MySQL Execute function not executing in python

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I am making a module I which data from a csv file is converted to a table in MySQL.

The execute function is  not executing the command for inserting rows to the table.

The method

```py
def add_to_mysql(self,username,password,database,table_name,add_rows = False):

    conn = my.connect(username = username, password = password)
    cursor1 = conn.cursor()

    cursor1.execute("USE "+database)
    cursor1.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name)
    command = """CREATE TABLE """+"""CLASSTABLE("""
    commands = []
    # getting information about datatype and value  
    for i in self.table_list[0]:
        prompt = "Enter data type of " + i + " (datatype(value))"
        datatype = input(prompt)
        command += "\n" + i + " " +datatype+","

    count = 0
    real_command = """"""

    for j in command:
        count += 1
        if count == len(command):
            real_command += ")"
        else:
            real_command += command[count-1]

    cursor1.execute(real_command)
    conn.close()

    def get_number_of_row_in():
        return (len(self.table_list))

    if add_rows:
        count = 0
        to_enter = "("
        real_command = """"""
        #String editing to make the command            
        for j in self.table_list[0]:
            to_enter += j+","
        real_to_enter = ""
        for j in to_enter:
            count += 1
            if count == len(to_enter):
                real_to_enter += ")"
            else:
                real_to_enter += to_enter[count - 1]
        command = 'INSERT INTO  `' + table_name + '`' + 'VALUES'
        command_to_reenter = command
        #more string editing
        def row_command():
            commands = []
            counter = 0
            command = 'INSERT INTO  `' + table_name + '`' + 'VALUES'
            to_enter = ''
            command_to_reenter = 'INSERT INTO  `' + table_name + '`' + 'VALUES'
            for i in self.table_list:
                if i == self.table_list[0]:
                    pass
                elif counter == get_number_of_row_in():
                    break
                else:
                    for j in i:
                        to_enter += j + ','
                    real_to_enter = ' ('
                    count = 0
                    for j in to_enter:
                        count += 1
                        if count == len(to_enter):
                            real_to_enter += ')'
                        else:
                            real_to_enter +=to_enter[count - 1]
                    counter += 1
                    command += real_to_enter
                    commands.append(command)
                    command += real_to_enter
                    to_enter = ""
                    real_to_enter = ""
                    command = command_to_reenter
            return commands
        conn1 = my.connect(username = username, password = password)
        cursor2 = conn1.cursor()
        cursor2.execute("USE "+database+";")
        for i in row_command():
            cursor2.execute(i)
        command = command_to_reenter

conn1.close()
```

Notes->
There ARE NOT ERRORS in the program
I CANNOT USE AN OTHER LIB
Even slightest Help is appreciated

Thank you for reading till here.

Comment: Remember to run `conn.commit()` after any DDL statement.

Comment: Provide your CSV to MySQL as-is and import the data using single LOAD DATA query.

Comment: Thank you You save my brain from exploding

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: I shouldn't have used DDL there. It could be for DDL *or* DML. Thanks for the comment.